Run custom target only when dependencies is modified
I'm using ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET to have my Visual Studio solution run cppcheck when being compiled:
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET( STATIC_CODE_ANALYSIS_QUIET ALL COMMAND cppcheck ${PATH_TO_SOURCES}/src )

(this is a MCVE, I have more arguments actually)
The problem is that the tool is ran whenever I build the solution, even if I did not modify any file from my src folder. It makes no sense, it should only run when a file was modified.
So I tried to add a DEPENDS parameter:
set( STATIC_CODE_ANALYSIS_DEPENDENCIES )
list( APPEND STATIC_CODE_ANALYSIS_DEPENDENCIES "${PATH_TO_SOURCES}/src/main.cpp" )
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET( STATIC_CODE_ANALYSIS_QUIET ALL COMMAND cppcheck ${PATH_TO_SOURCES}/src DEPENDS ${STATIC_CODE_ANALYSIS_DEPENDENCIES} )

But it makes no difference. I see the doc says "The target has no output file and is always considered out of date", so it's maybe intended. It looks like add_custom_command should be used to correctly handle "up to date"/"out to date" targets, however, cppcheck no being generating any "output file", I cannot create a "custom command" (which requires a OUTPUT parameter).
How can I have cppcheck be ran from Visual Studio automatically when I build the solution, but only if a file was modified since last run?
Note: using --output-file argument of cppcheck to use it as OUTPUT is not acceptable because then the output of the tool does not go to the Visual Studio console, which is required for the user to see if everything is OK or not.

For run a tool "conditionally", you need to use add_custom_command. If a tool doesn't generate a file, you may generate a dummy file manually by specifying additional COMMAND. BTW, exactly output file (and its timestamp) is used for determine whether dependencies have been modified since the last command run.

I can specify several COMMAND parameters? Or should I do something trivky to have a single COMMANDdo two operations in a row?

You could specify several COMMAND in add_custom_command run. Those commands will be executed sequentially (unless one of them is failed). This is described in documentation.

As Tsyvarev suggested, let's do two COMMAND in custom command and create a timestamp file manually.
# Static code analysis project:
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT           cppcheck.timestamp
    COMMAND          cppcheck
    ARGS             ${PATH_TO_SOURCES}/src
    COMMAND          date /t > cppcheck.timestamp
    COMMENT          "Running static code analysis..."
    VERBATIM
    DEPENDS          ${STATIC_CODE_ANALYSIS_DEPENDENCIES} )
# Add module:
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET( STATIC_CODE_ANALYSIS
    ALL
    SOURCES cppcheck.timestamp )

